# Force Close Android Unable to start activity

Tags: android, sqlite, forceclose

I press button show in class TestDBIIIIActivity to change interface from main to showdata. and
Popup is show Force Close.

From LogCat

```
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.testdbiiii/com.app.testdbiiii.ShowData}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at com.app.testdbiiii.ShowData.onCreate(ShowData.java:27)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-11 16:39:43.434: E/AndroidRuntime(13835):    ... 11 more
```

From Class TestDBIIIIActivity

```
public class TestDBIIIIActivity extends Activity {
Button add,show;
EditText name;
TextView time;
private DatabaseAdapter myDatabaseAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    show =(Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
    name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    time =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);

    myDatabaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    myDatabaseAdapter.openToWrite();

    add.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
    show.setOnClickListener(buttonShowClickListener);

}

Button.OnClickListener buttonShowClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShowData.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};

Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data1 = name.getText().toString();
        String data2 = time.getText().toString();
        myDatabaseAdapter.insert(data1, data2);

    }

};
```

}

From Class ShowData

```
public class ShowData extends ListActivity {
Button refresh;
private DatabaseAdapter myDatabaseAdapter;
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
Cursor cursor;
ListView listContent;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showdata);
    cursor = myDatabaseAdapter.queueAll();
    refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);   

    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.KEY_ID,DatabaseAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, DatabaseAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2 };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor,from, to);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    myDatabaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);

    refresh.setOnClickListener(buttonRefreshClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonRefreshClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        updateList();
    }

};


private void updateList() {
    cursor.requery();
}
```

}

From Class DatabaseAdapter

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Name";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Time";

// create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table "+ MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public DatabaseAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public DatabaseAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String name, String time) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT1, name);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT2, time);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}

public int deleteAll() {
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public Cursor queueAll() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2 };
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

}

Help me please.

Comment: Can we have the layout file(s) too please. It looks like it fails due to not being able to find 'android.R.id.list' but there maybe other issues.

Comment: @GrahamSmith
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4895678/showdata.txt http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4895678/main.txt http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4895678/list_item.txt 

I cannot edit.

Comment: OK thanks for that - will have a look.

Comment: People REALLY need to stop just posting code and say solve it for me. At the VERY least you should look into it yourself and post what you think it may be, and try to figure it out. This is starting to become sad. LEARN to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use listview  id as

```
 <Listview
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  ./>
```

Also use

```
      listcontent=getListView();
```

instead of

```
    listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a list view defined in your layout file as

android:id="@+id/contentlist" .../>

Or u have to access the android listview using android.R.id.list